# What open source software uses ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, open-source

I would like to see how other software is designed using the MVC technology. I am working on a small MVC project and would like ideas on how to design it. The only way to look at high quality code is to inspect other open source projects using the microsofts mvc technology.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298882/what-are-some-examples-of-good-open-source-asp-net-mvc-applications

Comment: This isn't really a question, and is more of a community wiki topic simply because there's no right or wrong answer (apart from 'this isn't open source' or 'this doesn't use ASP.NET MVC').

Answer (score 1):

[Oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/) is an open source, web standards compliant, blog engine built on ASP.NET MVC.

you can go to http://www.codeplex.com/ search "asp.net mvc"

Answer (score 0):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) has just gone open source.

I've had a look through it and it's a well designed, well written project with plenty of useful little tips and tricks. Their use of the `Current` static object is interesting and something I'm going to look at doing in the future.

Comment: I did not find how to checkout the source code?

Comment: @dushouke It uses Mercurial - http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/checkout